# quick time movie in glib

Tags: gtk, glib

How can i create a movie file using Glib. If there is a class for a movie then,

let me know the details for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/). What class you need depends on the encoding you would like to use in your movie file, but [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html) is a list of the available plugins.